# VirtualBox cleanup

Tags: discussion, off-topic, cleanup

This is long overdue...

There are currently [757 open questions](https://serverfault.com/search?q=%5Bvirtualbox%5D%20is%3Aquestion%20closed%3A0) under the [virtualbox](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/virtualbox) tag.

From a quick skim through some of them, it appears that the majority of them should be closed as off-topic, due to being personal environments, not system administration, utterly ridiculous and commercially unreasonable, etc.

The last time I checked, it appeared the consensus was that [most such questions about VirtualBox should be closed](https://meta.serverfault.com/q/5529/126632), unless they were obviously about system administration and/or in a production environment. From some informal conversations I've had with community members, this doesn't appear to have changed.

I propose that we go through a few of these questions (each) and vote to close those which need to be closed now (and probably should have been closed then). The point being to discourage further such off-topic questions from being posted.

This is a bit too big for moderators to handle alone, and the community should be involved anyway. If you're reading this, please pick a page at random from the [search results](https://serverfault.com/search?q=%5Bvirtualbox%5D%20is%3Aquestion%20closed%3A0) and spend a few minutes going through them.

Comment: ServerFault has suffered from a severe lack of drama lately, so I suggest we just get HBruijn to untag all the VBox questions and then bulk close them....

Answer (score 8):

The tag is not necessarily evil, but I have no doubt this is a hotspot for off-topic questions.  I intend to go through them on a case-by-case basis a bit, and I suggest other non-moderators do the same.  Since the close queue is growing, though, it might be nice to have a moderator assist to slam some of the clearer ones closed once they have a couple votes.

Answer (score -2):

I no longer work at the place where we used VBox on Ubuntu LTS for lots of our servers, so I've got no problem with helping close most of these.

Comment: I started by looking at the oldest questions, some of them are quite interesting actually, but the first one I looked at was a more abstract question and didn't involve VBox at all so I just re-tagged it.

Comment: Ome questions tagged virtualbox are about configuring it and deploying it for people to use, they are perfectly acceptable.

Answer (score -7):

In a normal site, "cleanup" means massive fixing, tagging, etc.

By you, "cleanup" means a massive content destruction, with year long retroactively applied rule.