# Is the response "Why do you even question this?" compatible with the new code of conduct?

Tags: discussion

I believe my recent question [should not have been migrated](https://meta.serverfault.com/q/9362/6832) to SuperUser. In the linked question, I tried to explain why I think that is the case.

Among other condescending replies, I got [this response](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/9362/i-think-my-question-was-mistakenly-closed-and-moved-to-superuser?noredirect=1#comment22439_9362) from another [moderator](https://meta.serverfault.com/users/8897/sven):

> Your question has been migrated to the place that can help you best with this. Why do you even question this?

How is that compatible with the new [Code of Conduct](https://meta.stackexchange.com/conduct)? Specifically, the part that states:

> No subtle put-downs or unfriendly language. Even if you don’t intend it, this can have a negative impact on others.

The fact that the mod thinks that I am so stupid to think that server admins might know how to override the choice of `systemd` for a default route in the guest operating system is rather unwelcoming.

I tried to explain as best I can that the original migration was mistaken. The three responses I got all say "shut up!" instead of pointing out how SuperUser is a better place to get an answer.

Of course, it may be the case that getting no answer is better than getting these types of responses.

Answer (score 7):

In my view, you are the one who behaved in a very unfriendly way. Not necessarily by questioning the migration, but by a part like

> This was done by an admin who thinks how to change to a directory, how to set an environment variable in a systemd service, how to install ImageMagick, and how to set a static IP address in OpenVPN, among others, were on-topic questions on ServerFault.

What is the purpose of this except ridiculing Michael Hampton?

That aside: Yes, I absolutely am convinced that me voicing my astonishment with your post is perfectly fine even under these absurdly stupid CoC rules. Really, I don't get it - your question has been migrated, not closed and I absolutely don't understand why you and many others in your situation don't just accept it and move on.

Comment: "*ridiculing Michael Hampton*" ... I am not ridiculing him. I am pointing out that he had no problem with a number of questions that might very reasonably be considered appropriate for other sites but for whatever reason he thought a question about overriding the default route chosen by `systemd` was not appropriate here. I know a thing or two and I explained my reasoned argument that a) the migration was mistaken; and b) it seems not to be consistent with the *moderator*'s own choices in the past.

Comment: I don't feel particularly ridiculed. But there being no apparent relevance of those other posts to this one, I'm going to ask that you post a new question if you wish to discuss them.